# Como volver a ejecutar una sentencia sql mediante ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, poo

tengo la duda de como puedo volver a ejecutar la sentencia sql de nuevo, al enviar el formulario mediante ajax.

Aqui el codigo de la sentencia que se ejecuta

```
$conexion = $this->conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND pass = ?";

        $consulta_preparada = $conexion->prepare($sql);

        $consulta_preparada->execute(array($this->nombre, $this->pass));

        //rowCount devuelve el numero de filas con las que ha coincidido, 1 o 0

        $login = $consulta_preparada->rowCount();

        if ($login > 0) {

            $datos = new stdClass();

            $datos->permiso = "1";
            $datos->usuario = "Shum";
            $datos->edad = "18";

            header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

            $this->json= json_encode($datos);

        }else {

            $datos = new stdClass();

            $datos->permiso = "0";

            header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

            $this->json = json_encode($datos);

        }

        $this->conexion = null;
```

una vez que se ejecuta me devuelve los datos todo normal y fino, pero cuando inserto otro nombre y le doy a enviar no pasa nada, es decir no ejecuta la consulta, sin embargo si lo hago con if-else si lo hace (obvio es de prueba), por ejemplo:

```
if ($nombre == "Shum") {

    retorna algo

}else if () {

    retorna algo 

}else if () {

    retorna algo
}
```

y si se actualiza el formulario, como puedo hacerlo pero con la consulta? espero que me entiendan xD, gracias :)

Comment: En el php no parece haber ningún problema, muestranos como llamas a ese código desde la vista.

Comment: Sería conveniente que incluyas el código javascript desde donde lo llamas. Por otro lado, yo al menos, no entiendo mucho la lógica. Haces la select y luego asignas el nombre de usuario? donde está el código que pones abajo de los ifs encadenados?

Comment: "No devuelve nada" significa que devuelve `'{"permiso": 0}'` o que sigue devolviendo `'{"permiso":1, "nombre": "Shum"}'` ?